# bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 1.8.7 related to Bundle RVM and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, segmentation-fault, rvm, bundler

Rails config problem I guess.  I have an error in my config that just occurred.  The only thing I recall doing since the app was working is:

> % gem install taps

Current state

Mac:mecv2 me$ ruby script/server
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p174@mecv2/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/http11.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i686-darwin10.7.0]

Abort trap

--

I'm using RVM and Bundler too.
ruby-1.8.7-p174@mecv2:

Does anyone know if the following gems are incompatible?

- sudo gem update --system 1.5 #to downgrade rubygems for compatibility
- taps (0.3.23)
- sequel (3.20.0)
- pg (0.11.0)  # sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg

Or maybe its something else?
when I installed the taps and sequel gems I did not use RVM nor bundler.  I just did sudo gem install X.

Comment: Output of the command which gem?

Comment: Why are you using "gem install" when you are using bundler?